# Quickly mass scrape Facebook fan pages' numeric IDs

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, scrapy, scrape

Many Facebook fan pages are now in the following format - https://www.facebook.com/TiltedKiltEsplanade where "TiltedKiltEsplanade" is an example of the name claimed by the page owner. However, the same page's RSS feed is found at https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=414117051979234&format=rss20 where 414117051979234 is an ID that can be determined by going to https://**graph**.facebook.com/TiltedKiltEsplanade and looking for the last numeric ID listed on the page (there are two similar-looking IDs at the top of the page but these can be ignored).

I have a long list of Facebook fan pages in the format described above and I would like to quickly grab the numeric IDs that correspond to those pages so that I can add all of them to an RSS reader. What would be the simplest way to scrape these pages? I am familiar with Scrapy but I'm not sure if it can be used because the graph version of the page isn't marked up in a way that allows for easy scraping (as far as I can tell)

Thanks.

Comment: `What would be the simplest way to scrape these pages?` Probably with some code! I would recommend checking this out - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back if you run into more specific questions, after you've done some research and begun to code this yourself.

Comment: I understand the basics of Python and have used Scrapy before to scrape sites but I am not sure if it can be used for this project given the mark up of the code. I should have been more specific in my original question.

Comment: I would really just like it if some could look at the URL starting with graph and see if there is a way to code that in Scrapy. I do not need the coding done for me. I would just like to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of the graph request is a JSON object. That's way more easy to process than HTML content.

This would be a simple implementation of what you are looking for:

```
# file: myspider.py
import json

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = (
        # Add here more urls. Alternatively, make the start urls dynamic
        # reading them from a file, db or an external url.
        'https://www.facebook.com/TiltedKiltEsplanade',
    )

    graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{name}'
    feed_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id={id}&format=rss20'

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            # This assumes there is no trailing slash
            name = url.rpartition('/')[2]
            yield Request(self.graph_url.format(name=name), self.parse_graph)

    def parse_graph(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        return Request(self.feed_url.format(id=data['id']), self.parse_feed)

    def parse_feed(self, response):
        # You can use the xml spider, xml selector or the feedparser module
        # to extract information from the feed.
        self.log('Got feed: %s' % response.body[:100])
```

The output:

```
$ scrapy runspider myspider.py
2014-01-11 02:19:48-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.21.0-97-g21a8a94 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-01-11 02:19:48-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2014-01-11 02:19:48-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {}
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [myspider] INFO: Spider opened
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [myspider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-01-11 02:19:49-0400 [myspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://graph.facebook.com/TiltedKiltEsplanade> (referer: None)
2014-01-11 02:19:50-0400 [myspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=414117051979234&format=rss20> (referer: https://graph.facebook.com/TiltedKiltEsplanade)
2014-01-11 02:19:50-0400 [myspider] DEBUG: Got feed: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0"
          xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com
2014-01-11 02:19:50-0400 [myspider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-01-11 02:19:50-0400 [myspider] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 578,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 6669,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 11, 6, 19, 50, 849162),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
     'log_count/INFO': 3,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 11, 6, 19, 49, 221361)}
2014-01-11 02:19:50-0400 [myspider] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I sincerely appreciate that you actually created the entire code structure for me as I know it would have taken me quite awhile to figure out. 

When I try and output the results to a CSV using this code - scrapy crawl myspider -o FB.csv -t csv - the resulting file is empty. Could you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @zgall1 Are you returning an Item object? I'd suggest to create a new question adding more details about your spider code, the output logs, etc.

Comment: I simply ran the code you provided. Now that I look at it more carefully, I see that it doesn't return an Item object (like the code I have created previously). I'll see if I can modify what you have done. Thanks.